# Notification popup android

Tags: android, notifications, popup

I have made a notification and it displays in the status bar. However, in other apps, I have seen that initially, the notification pops up on the screen and then goes to the status bar. How do I make that happen?

Thanks

Comment: When you build your notification object, try to set its priority to Notification.PRIORITY_MAX

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Glad to here that!